# NGINX Allow/Deny based on IP & User Agent combination

Tags: nginx

I have CI environment that use basic authentication to block user's.
but i want to allow facebook google pinterest and other social sharing to access my env.

Google and Facebook have a list of ip's that i need to allow, but pinterest have only user agent.

Im using now the command "allow some.ip.for.example"  for allowing the google and facebook.
how can i mix it with pinterest user agent? "Pinterest"

Thanks,
Elad

Comment: `0.0.0.0` means all IP addresses.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 was only example how i allow google and facebook to crwal my site

Comment: It breaks your authentication system